# how to sort particular columns row in datatable using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, sorting, datatable

eg:-

```
var Rows = (from row in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                            orderby row["Amount"] descending
                            select row);
```

if table like this

```
              RegId     Name

              101       jone

              102       Raj

              103       guru

       i want output like this using c# DataTable

              RegId     Name

              103       jone

              102       Raj

              101       guru
```

i want sort only the regid column rows

Comment: You are not showing the column `Amount`. So you want to order one column but keep the rest of the column in their old order? Strange requirement, are the columns not related to each other?

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort `RegId` column without changing the order of values in `Name` column?

Comment: Yes'I want like that only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to order one column but keep the rest of the column in their old order? Strange requirement, are the columns not related to each other?

However, following code will select the desired column and order it descending. Then the `DataTable` will be updated with the new values of this column:

```
List<int> amountsOrdered = dt1.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<int>("Amount"))
    .OrderByDescending(i => i)
    .ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
    dt1.Rows[i].SetField("Amount", amountsOrdered[i]);
```

Note that the `Field` extension method is strongly typed what is a good thing. But it can cause an exception if your column's type is `string`. Then you first need to `Parse` it to `int` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regIds = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                .Cast<DataRow>()
                .Select(r => (int)r["Amount"])
                .OrderByDescending(id => id)
                .ToArray();

for(int i=0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt1.Rows[i];
    row["Amount"] = regIds[i];
}
```

Make sure you disable the constraints (if any) on the uniqueness of `Amount` column of your data table. More info in the [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.constraints.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

if you can use dataview, then you can simple use dataview.sort = "expression"
otherwise i think there is no default option to sort data table, other than looping